# UIView not cover UIWindow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiwindow

[image: Black screen]

[image: View in debug]

I'm using `MFSideMenu` which instantiated in `AppDelegate`, if I call

```
 `CMainViewController *vMain = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CMainView"];
[navigationController pushViewController:vMain animated:YES];`
```

It works fine, if I not do a call (automatically view created) and inside this view do a call - I have the issue.

Any ideas - thanks in advance!

Find the place:
If I call pushViewController inside UIAlertView - I get the issue, if outside it works.

[[WashappService sharedInstance] auth:^(BOOL value) {
            if(value==TRUE){
                [self presentViewController:[LoginController authConfirmScreen:self toUser:user toPhone:szPhone  success:^{

```
                [(MenuClientController*)self.menuContainerViewController.leftMenuViewController updateData];

                User* user = [User new];
                user = [UserPreference get:KEY_CLIENT];
                user.typeOwner = self.isWashAdmin;
                [UserPreference save:KEY_CLIENT toValue:user];
                [[WashappService sharedInstance] updateToken:user.token];

                if (self.isWashAdmin){
                    OOrdersViewController *vMain = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OOrdersViewController"];
                    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vMain animated:YES];
                }else{
                    CMainViewController *vMain = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CMainView"];
```

//                        vMain.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
                        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vMain animated:YES];
                    }
                }] animated:YES completion:nil];

```
        }
```

Comment: Where is your root view controler code ?

Comment: The root view is MFSideMenuContainerViewController (pod component).

In AppDelegate use this code

Comment: UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = (MFSideMenuContainerViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MFSideMenuContainerViewController"];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainNavigationController"];
    UIViewController *rightSideMenuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewMenuController"];